# Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods error

Tags: angularjs

i have developed a front end to a RESTAPI using angularjs when i try to write a DELETE using $resource it will give me following error

Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Comment: So...does the server you're trying to connect to support DELETE?

Comment: @Makoto yes it is supporting to DELETE. when i used google advanced rest client and send the same API call through that it works fine.

Comment: Is the REST API public ? If so, could you provide it for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also doing the something with angular but I hope this may help you. Here is a solution: 
First have to update in your API web.config file

```
<clear />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE" />

In `ApiController`

[HttpDelete]
public string Delete() 
{ 
return "u call delete"; 
} 

public HttpResponseMessage Options() { 
     var response = new HttpResponseMessage(); 
     response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK; 
return response; 
}


In Angular...

        home.post().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        home.remove().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

Out Put...

> u call delete

Hope this will help you.. :)
```

Answer (score -1):

you cant access DELETE because its not allow from the server, so: 
1. you could change that when you are the owner of the restapi 
2. look in the docs of the the API for more information, how to arrive your goal

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is a nice posts to this tobic

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa.  Not what you're thinking about.  This is talking about making a RESTful call to a service, which is perfectly possible to do in JavaScript.

Comment: sure, but the server of him doesn´t allow DELETE as method and thats also described in the link of my post, so he can understand why this doesn´t work for him

....i edited my posts ;)

Comment: i have gone through the api docs it says that the DELETE is allowed. when i send the same API call using google advanced rest client it works just fine